# Отложенный запрос сертификата клиента (nginx)

Tags: nginx, kestrel

Nginx 1.14.1.
Необходима аутентификация на клиентских сертификатах, но не для всего сайта (https://example.net), или приложения на нем (https://example.net/app1), а только по определенному пути в приложении (https://example.net/app1/auth/smartcard).
Приложение на Net6 (c#, asp.net).
При отладке используя сервер kestrel, без без обратного прокси-сервера nginx, я этого добился путем указания опции ClientCertificateMode.DelayCertificate:

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args, IConfiguration config) =>
           Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
               {
                   webBuilder.UseConfiguration(config)
                   .UseStartup<Startup>()
                   .ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
                   {
                       var connectionOptions = new HttpsConnectionAdapterOptions();
                    
                       // Отложенный запрос сертификата клиента.
                       connectionOptions.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.DelayCertificate;
                       // ...
                       serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 15126, listenOptions =>
                       {
                           listenOptions.UseHttps(connectionOptions);
                       });
                    })
               });
```

Теперь, при обращении к https://localhost:15126, сертификат клиента не запрашивается.
А при обращении к https://localhost:15126/auth/smartcard - запрашивается:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "SmartCardPolicy", AuthenticationSchemes = CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[RequireHttps]
public async Task<IActionResult> SmartCard(string returnUrl = null)
{
}
```

Когда я публикую приложение app1 на сервере, и указываю в /etc/nginx/sites-available/default только

```
location /app1 {
    #...
    proxy_set_header  X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_escaped_cert;
    #...
}
```

То сертификат клиента не запрашивается ни при открытии https://example.net, ни при https://example.net/app1, ни при https://example.net/app1/auth/smartcard

Если я укажу в файле /etc/nginx/sites-available/default в директиве server опции

```
ssl_client_certificate /path-ca.pem;
#ssl_verify_client on;
#ssl_verify_client optional;
ssl_verify_client optional_no_ca;
```

то запрос сертификата будет просто при открытии https://example.net/, равно как и https://example.net/app1, https://example.net/app2, https://example.net/appN.
Я пробовал изменять значение параметра ssl_verify_client в "on", "optional" и "optional_no_ca", ожидая что хотя бы одна из этих опций разрешить принимать сертификат клиента, но при этом не отправлять клиенту запрос на сертификат (как это делает ClientCertificateMode.DelayCertificate в kestrel), однако запрос на сертификат выходит всегда.

Приложение app1 - это сервис, поддерживающий несколько типов аутентификации. Важно, чтобы при его посещении (или других приложений на https://example.net), запрос сертификата выдавался только в определенной точке. Как этого добиться через nginx?
Я могу опубликовать app1 самостоятельно, без обратного прокси, но это небезопасно, т.к. kestrel нужно прятать.

Comment: ssl сертификаты выпускаются на домены (поддомены), но не для определенного request_uri. SSL сертификаты используются для целей шифрования, а не для целей авторизации.

Comment: Шифрование будет и без использования сертификата клиента: за счет публичного сертификата веб-сервера, выдаваемого клиенту. Тут же - именно аутентификация, когда клиент предоставляет свой сертификат. Для kestrel один и тот же сертификат, однако при открытии приложения на kestrel, запрос КЛИЕНТУ на сертификат не выдается, а выдается только по пути /app/auth/smardcard.

Comment: В kestrel ClientCertificateMode.DelayCertificate делает именно это:не запрашивает сертификат при обращению к kestrel, однако потом, защитив метод в контроллере схемой авторизации, основанной на смарт-картах, запрашивается: https://learn-microsoft-com.translate.goog/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.https.clientcertificatemode?view=aspnetcore-7.0&_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=ru&_x_tr_hl=ru&_x_tr_pto=wapp
Значение optional ssl_verify_client ЗАПРАШИВАЕТ сертификат,но клиент при этом может отказатя его предоставлять - ошибки не будет, будут предприняты попытки другой аутентификации